# Inconsistent string formatting with an alignment component

Tags: c#, string-formatting, bidi

I'm trying to output some field aligned data in an application ([see Alignment Component on this MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx)).

I've noticed that some strings do not align correctly on the field boundary.

This is most obvious with this small bit of sample code that just outputs a number as currency in all cultures to a text file.

```
var value = 5000.95;
using (var writer = new StreamWriter("c:\\test.txt"))
{
    foreach (var culture in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures).OrderBy(c => c.Name))
    {
        writer.WriteLine($"{value.ToString("C2", culture),-20}{culture.Name,-10}");
    }
}
```

This is an example of the improperly aligned output using left alignment:

```
R 5,000.95          af        
R 5,000.95          af-ZA     
ETB5,000.95         am        
ETB5,000.95         am-ET     
ر.س.‏ 5,000.95      ar        
د.إ.‏ 5,000.95      ar-AE     
د.ب.‏ 5,000.95      ar-BH     
د.ج.‏ 5,000.95      ar-DZ     
ج.م.‏ 5,000.95      ar-EG     
د.ع.‏ 5,000.95      ar-IQ     
د.ا.‏ 5,000.95      ar-JO
```

This is an example using right alignment:

```
          R 5,000.95     af-ZA
         ETB5,000.95        am
         ETB5,000.95     am-ET
      ر.س.‏ 5,000.95        ar
      د.إ.‏ 5,000.95     ar-AE
      د.ب.‏ 5,000.95     ar-BH
      د.ج.‏ 5,000.95     ar-DZ
      ج.م.‏ 5,000.95     ar-EG
      د.ع.‏ 5,000.95     ar-IQ
      د.ا.‏ 5,000.95     ar-JO
      د.ك.‏ 5,000.95     ar-KW
      ل.ل.‏ 5,000.95     ar-LB
       د.ل.‏5,000.95     ar-LY
      د.م.‏ 5,000.95     ar-MA
          $ 5.000,95       arn
          $ 5.000,95    arn-CL
```

You can see that the formatting for cultures containing unicode are not correctly aligned at the 20 character position as the documentation says it should be.  It is also throwing the fields to the right outside of their field boundaries.  This issue seems to be mostly confined to cultures that format currency using Unicode.

Is there a good way to adjust for this problem?

Comment: Farsi (fa-IR) is a right-to-left language.  I'm curious, if you change the alignment to `-20`, does it align that line as desired?

Comment: @Amy when using a negative alignment, the currency portion is correctly left-aligned, but some of the following fields are pushed to the left.  I'll add some example output using -20.

Comment: A basic workaround (I'm hesitant to call it a 'solution') would be to check if the culture is right-to-left, and if so, flip the sign on the alignment component.  I would expect the language to more directly support this sort of thing though.  Adding the "bidi" (bi-directional) tag to the question.

Comment: I've added an example when using -20, unfortunately I get an error adding a screenshot where the error is more apparent, I'll keep trying.  I was able to upload the screenshot directly to imgur, but embedding it still gives an error on stack-overflow, so it is linked for now.

Comment: @BradleyUffner String interpolation is a syntactic sugar on top of the String.Format... so it will have the same issues as String.Format.

Comment: @loneshark99 yup, I updated the question to note that it isn't specific to string interpolation after exploring some more.

Comment: The issue is entirely due to the right-to-left characters in the string. The formatted string does in fact place those characters (in the `fa-IR` case) after the numeric digits representing the number (which are normal left-to-right characters), and does in fact place the entire sequence of characters in a field that is 20 characters long. So, this actually has _nothing_ to do with `string.Format()`. That method is doing exactly what you tell it to. The real issue has to do with how the text is rendered, and that's entirely dependent on the actual real-world situation.

Comment: The exact alignment cannot possibly be that important in a `Debug.WriteLine()` output, so presumably this came up in some other scenario. Unfortunately, there's not any context in the question that would lead anyone to a useful solution for that scenario. Please fix the question so that it includes a good [mcve] that provides all of the necessary context required to provide an answer that's actually useful to you.

Comment: (And if I'm mistaken and all you really do care about is getting the `Debug.WriteLine()` output to comply with your expectation, well...I'm sure there's some hack that can force the output to look the way you want, but IMHO it'll be _way_ more trouble than it's worth to figure out.)

Comment: In the actual application, the output is being directed to a data file, which is sent to a processing service.  The processing service expects a field-width delimited file.  It doesn't care about the alignment of the data within the field, but it must be contained within the field boundaries.  These formatting issues are causing subsequent fields on the same line to be shifted to the left, outside their field boundaries.  Unfortunately I'm not permitted to share the actual output of the file with real data in it.

Comment: I updated the question to write to a file instead of the console, it doesn't change anything about the output.  I was just trying to keep the example code as simple as possible.